# Oracle Enterprise Manager Database Express shows common users only

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-enterprise-manager

Users page under security menu in Oracle EM Database Express shows common users only as shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

All pluggable databases are opened and can be accessed using SQL*PLUS.

Comment: All pluggable database are open. I can connect to them from sqlplus

Answer (score 2):

Since you are connected to the root container you only get list of common users.

First of all connect to the PDB and check whether http/https port is configured or not.

```
SQL> conn sys@orapdb1 as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> select dbms_xdb_config.gethttpsport() from dual;

DBMS_XDB_CONFIG.GETHTTPSPORT()
------------------------------
                 0
```

In my case it has not been set, so I am going to set it.

```
SQL>  exec dbms_xdb_config.sethttpsport(5501);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Now go to the url<`https://hostname:5501/em`> and try open the user page you will get all the users. Make sure you are connected to the PDB as shown in the following screenshot.

[image]